# How to remove voice-port directive from IOS Configuration

Tags: cisco-voip

I'm running an old Cisco 1751-V for years now as ISDN-SIP-Gateway. Deutsche Telekom is getting rid of ISDN more and more and lately, ISDN-VoIP config is no longer necessary on my side. Since the router handles additional duties, I deconfigured the ISDN- and VoIP-stuff with the appropriate *no*-command forms.

I can't do that on *voice-port* configurations, though:

```
voipgw(config)#no voice-port 0/0
% Cannot remove voice-ports this way
```

Q: How am I supposed to remove voice-ports?

Searching the net for the error message yields no really helpful advice. One source states that one has to remove the appropriate hardware but since I deconfigured and shut the appropriate BRI-Interfaces, I think this is not a solution applicable to remote managed devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`voice-port` refers to *physical hardware*, so you can't "`no`" it away. It has to be physically removed from the router -- if possible, or simply shut it down.

Comment: After erasing the startup configuration and display of running-config, the ports indeed are still existing but there's no (visible) configuration for these, now.

Answer (score 0):

`voice-port 0/0` enters the configuration context for that port. `show voice port summary` should show you what you can do there.